# php image upload problem in IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, uploading

I got this php uploading script which is working fine on Mozilla, Chrome, Opera, Safari :

```
$image1=$_FILES['file1']['name'];
if ($image1)
{
    $filename1 = stripslashes($_FILES['file1']['name']);
    $extension1 = getExtension($filename1);
    $extension1 = strtolower($extension1);
    if (($extension1 != "jpg") && ($extension1 != "jpeg")  && ($extension1 != "gif") && ($extension1 != "png"))
    {
        $errors=1;
    }
    else
    {
        $size1=filesize($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']);
    list($width1, $height1, $type1, $attr1) = getimagesize($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name']);
    if($width1>=100 and $height1>100)
    {
        if ($size1 > MAX_SIZE*1024)
        {
            $errors=1;
        }
    else
    {
            $newname1="../wallImages/".$image1;
            $copied1 = copy($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], $newname1);
            if (!$copied1)
            {
                $errors=1;
            }
    }
    }
    else
    {
    $errors=1;
    }
}
}
```

My problem occurs only in IE and when try to upload an image I got the 
`error no 4 - UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`

Please help me as I have no clue what to do to solve the problem

Thank you

Comment: try simple upload .... and post the error you got

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE likes to think that jpegs have the 'image/pjpeg' mime type (instead of 'image/jpeg'). That could be be the reason. I would suggest posting your implementation for `getExtension()`, or making sure that pjpeg is one of your allowed extensions.

Comment: I can post the getExtension() but in IE I wont get to that code because $image1 would be empty and exits the loop ... so the problem is that in IE the $_FILES['file1']['error'] is 4 and $_FILES['file1']['name'] is empty

Answer (score 1):

Would help if you could point the line number highlight the line on which you get this error

or you can refer to this simple example it works fine : http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_file_upload.asp

hope this helps.

Thanks
Ravi Mudaliar

Comment: thanks for help Ravi .. I dont get an specific error ... but when debuging the script I noticed that the $image1=$_FILES['file1']['name'] declaration will assign null to $image1 and also $_FILES['file1']['error'] is set to 4 ... and this only in IE ... so the exact same code will work fine in other browsers